# issue with clear content in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, textview

I am facing one issue for updating `TextView` content  in `RelativeLayout`. When I update in the second time, I need to clear the previous text from `RelativeLayout`.

I have one `RelativeLayout` in my app `activity_calendar.xml`

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rel_container"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linearLayout1">

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the Main Code :

```
public void listall () {
  RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rel_container);
    int prevTextViewId = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < titleCalendar.length; i++) {
        final TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setText(titleCalendar[i]);
        cnvrttime = hourCalendar[i] - 3;
        addcnvrtTime = 60*cnvrttime;
        curTextViewId = prevTextViewId + 1;
        textView.setId(curTextViewId);
        final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, addcnvrtTime);
        params.setMargins(0, convertDPtoInt((float)addcnvrtTime), 0, 0);
        textView.setLayoutParams(params);

        prevTextViewId = curTextViewId;
        relativeLayout.addView(textView, params);

}
```

Comment: Any reason you are not using either a linearLayout for this, or a ListView ?

Comment: so can i remove the text when i use the linearlayout?

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the TextView an id so you can find it later:

```
textView.setId(1234);
```

Then later:

```
TextView textView = findViewById(1234);
textView.setText("New Text");
```

Comment: You don't need to 'clear' the text, if you call setText() it will place that text in the view, overwriting the previous text there.

Answer (score 0):

If there aren't any child Views inside the relative layout that you want to keep, call `relativeLayout.removeAllViews()` before your `for` loop. Otherwise, use `removeView(View)` or `removeViewAt(int)` to remove the ones you don't want.